# dlopen Symbol not found: _PyClass_Type

Tags: python, macos, jupyter

[image]

I wonder how can I solve it .?

Comment: please post code.

Comment: Welcome to SO. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) on how to give a minimal, complete and verifiable example to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure why you are getting comments asking you to post your code - you have done so and your problem is caused by the line

```
import holoviews as hv
```

Looking at the stack trace it says that in `/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site_packages/params/__init__.so` there is a reference to _Py_ClassType and that symbol has not been defined.

A *.so file is a compiled file that is called by Python, usually written in C and built during the install process. I would have to guess that your install process did not complete.  To give a better answer I would have to see the install messages / logs.

Comment: Thanks! I solved the problem by uninstalling the holoviews and param libraries and installed them again.

Comment: Please accept the answer if it led to a solution.  Thanks.